# Space Complexity of Recursive Build-Heap

Tags: recursion, data-structures, heap, space-complexity

I am trying to resolve the space complexity of the recursive form of Build-Heap.
This is what I've done so far, and I would like to know where are my mistakes (if there are):

first of all: Build-Heap is constructed of for-loop, its' time complexity is Theta(n).

Build-Heap calls Heapify-Down Theta(n) times-(due to Build-Heap time complexity), so:
Heapify-Down pushes to the space-stack an array of n\i elements each i-recursive-call, this means it uses space complexity of Theta(logn).

In conclusion: Theta(n)*Theta(logn) = Theta(nlogn).

I'm not sure about my explanation for the number of time Heapify-Down being called, also i found on the interenet that Build-Heap space complexity is actually Theta(logn) which means my conclusions are wrong.
Thanks ahead.

Answer (score 0):

Your conclusion is absolutely right when it's a heap sort since the call to BUILD-MAX-HEAP takes
time O(n) and each of the n - 1 calls to MAX-HEAPIFY takes time O(log n).So the total running time would be O(nlogn).

You could refer to introduction to algorithms by Cormen, Leiserson, and Rivest for a detailed explanation

Comment: Thanks alot for your effort, my meaning is for Build-Heap or Build-Max-Heap but by means of SPACE COMPLEXITY and not time complexity. Do you have anything to say about the space complexity of Build-Heap? (also, I dont mean to heap sort).
but still, thank you for your time.